# Hardware revision number bluetooth chip

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm working on a project with a bluetooth chip and I need to know the **hardware revision number**.

Does anyone know how I can detect this for a bluetooth device ?

I don't find anything in the [docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html)